# CSS3: border on a border-radius div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a border property on a div that is using a border-radius property.

Here's my CSS:

```
#page {
    border: 1px solid #beb2b2;
    width: 732px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

So as you can see I just put a border radius (with all different properties for each browser) as well as a border of 1px. The problem is border isn't drawn on both top corners. It's drawn everywhere else including bottom corners. I looked for something on google but can't find anything...

Any idea ?

Comment: if you make it `border: 3px` does it show anything? I have the feeling it's a rendering issue that makes the border not aligning properly.

Comment: Just tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7DQEw/) and seems to work fine in FF and Chrome.

Comment: I think I understood my mistake, trying to fix that and I'll post further information about this. By the way, adding height doesn't change anything, it might be because I'm using an image as background for my div libelled "page" and it's overriding the border.

Comment: @Zuul **NOT** check demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2931000

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2931000) with `background-image` is working with `border-radius`

Comment: The problem is, the image was in a child div named "header" thus overriding parent div borders, i fixed it using `border-top-left-radius: 15px` on header div

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser as i say problem was in another markup )

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov yep, thing is your answer put me on the right track but doesn't contain the exact solution so maybe you'd like to add something to it so I can accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in the other markup and styles, because **your css is correct**: [*testcase on dabblet*](http://dabblet.com/gist/2931000)
[image]

Try to add some margin: `#page { margin: 15px; }` May be border is simple **invisible** or **container** of `#page` hide `border` with **`overflow: hidden;`**

**Update:** Problem also may be exists in inner `image`s which can override or ignore some parent properties (e.g `border-radius`).

Answer (score 0):

The page height is not defined. That is why it is spanning the whole window and you are not able to see the other borders.

Maybe that's the reason it's not working.

I just made some changes. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/5jGJj/).

### HTML

```
<div id=page></div>​
```

### CSS

```
#page {
    border: 1px solid #beb2b2;
    width: 732px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px auto; /* the extra line */
    height: 200px; /* the extra line */
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess due to some issue with height the bottom part is will be hiding, can you set some height on it.